# GPUImage2 use SolidColorGenerator as a RectangleGenerator

Tags: swift, face-detection, gpuimage

Similar to the simpleVideoFilter and face detection, I would like to highlight a portion of my GPUImage2 video feed with colored rectangles. The SolidColorGenerator seems like a good start with two exceptions. First, I am unsure how to transpose the SolidColorGenerator output to the right place on my original image. Second, I am unsure how to add N rectangles to my original image. In the mean time I have had success with the LineGenerator but I think a rectangle would look better.

Bonus:
Rectangles with rounded corners and a single pixel border.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was writing a RectangleGenerator. The key to the new RectangleGenerator was to draw GL_TRIANGLES.

```
glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), 0, GLsizei(positions.count) * 2)
```

One optimization that could be made would be to use GL_Elements and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, though I was not able to figure that out.

[image]

The full solution should support border, borderWidth and cornerRadius. For now simple rectangles will suffice. Full code below.

```
let vertex = "attribute vec4 position; void main(){ gl_Position = position; }"

let fragment = "uniform lowp vec3 fillColor; void main(){ gl_FragColor = vec4(fillColor, 1.0); }"

public class RectangleGenerator: ImageGenerator {

let rectangleShader:ShaderProgram
var uniformSettings = ShaderUniformSettings()

public var fillColor:Color = Color.green { didSet { uniformSettings["fillColor"] = fillColor } }

public override init(size:Size) {
    rectangleShader = crashOnShaderCompileFailure("RectangleGenerator"){try sharedImageProcessingContext.programForVertexShader(vertex, fragmentShader:fragment)}
    super.init(size:size)

    ({fillColor = Color.green})()
}

public func renderRectangles(_ positions:[Position]) {
    guard positions.count > 3 else { return }

    imageFramebuffer.activateFramebufferForRendering()

    rectangleShader.use()
    uniformSettings.restoreShaderSettings(rectangleShader)
    clearFramebufferWithColor(Color.transparent)

    guard let positionAttribute = rectangleShader.attributeIndex("position") else { fatalError("A position attribute was missing from the shader program during rendering.") }

    let convertedPositions = positions.flatMap{$0.toGLArray()}
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, 0, convertedPositions)

    glBlendEquation(GLenum(GL_FUNC_ADD))
    glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_ONE), GLenum(GL_ONE))
    glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))

    glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), 0, GLsizei(positions.count) * 2)
    glDisable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))

    notifyTargets()
}
}
```

Happy Coding